# ¿Como Hacer un Carrito de compras basico?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

estoy haciendo un carrito de compras pero no se como ir agregando productos al carrito, y que al final me sume todos los productos que tengo y despues me haga llenar un formulario de dirección y todo, ahora estoy haciendo por cada producto colocando el formulario, se que no es fiable asi. Solamente uso front end.

Aca tengo la vista del producto y tengo el formulario hay mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="align-self-center collapse navbar-collapse flex-fill  d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-between" id="templatemo_main_nav">
            <div class="flex-fill">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-between mx-lg-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Nosotros</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="shop.html">Productos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar align-self-center d-flex">
                <div class="d-lg-none flex-sm-fill mt-3 mb-4 col-7 col-sm-auto pr-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMobileSearch" placeholder="Search ...">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="nav-icon d-none d-lg-inline" href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#templatemo_search">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search text-dark mr-2"></i>
                </a>
<!--Carrito de Compras-->>
                <a class="nav-icon position-relative text-decoration-none" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-cart-arrow-down text-dark mr-1"></i>
                    <span class="position-absolute top-0 left-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-light text-dark">7</span>
                </a>
                <a class="nav-icon position-relative text-decoration-none" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user text-dark mr-3"></i>
                    <span class="position-absolute top-0 left-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-light text-dark">+99</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

esa parte es el formulario de mi producto, entonces lo estoy haciendo por cada producto un formulario pero se que no es bueno hacerlo.

```
 <div class="col-lg-7 mt-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h1 class="h2">Audifonos Apple iPhone Original Earpods jack 35mm Microfono</h1>
                        <p class="h3 py-2">$15.000</p>
                        <p class="py-2">
                            <i class="fa fa-star text-warning"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star text-warning"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star text-warning"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star text-warning"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star text-secondary"></i>
                            <span class="list-inline-item text-dark">Ranking 5.0</span>
                        </p>
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <h6>Marca: Apple</h6>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <p class="text-muted"><strong>Fácil de Usar</strong></p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <h6>Description:</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse. Donec condimentum elementum convallis. Nunc sed orci a diam ultrices aliquet interdum quis nulla.</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <h6>Avaliable Color :</h6>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <p class="text-muted"><strong>White / Black</strong></p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>


                        <form>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                              <label for="exampleInputName1" class="form-label">Nombre Completo</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" aria-describedby="nameLabel1" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                              <label for="exampleInputTelefono1" class="form-label">Telefono</label>
                              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTelefono1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Correo Electrónico</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
                              </div>
                            <div class="mb-3 form-check">
                              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                          </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar el procedimiento necesitas JavaScript. Como tu página se va a ir refrescando cada vez que vayas a la sección del carrito (y no estás usando React), necesitas guardarlo en un `sessionStorage`.
Supongamos que tenés un array en el cual se van almacenando todos tus productos, a ese array lo vamos a subir al `sessionStorage` de la siguiente forma:

```
let cart = []
sessionStorage.setItem("carrito", cart)
```

Cada vez que agregues un producto, eliminá el array existente y añadilo de nuevo. Supongamos:

```
let newCart = [product]
sessionStorage.removeItem("carrito")
/*siempre utiliza el mismo nombre (key) para agregar y eliminar el carrito*/
sessionStorage.setItem("carrito",newCart)
```

Y para obtener items del carrito, utiliza:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("carrito")
```

**Tip:**

El sessionStorage suele borrarse rapido, asi que cada vez que entrés a una nueva sección recomendaría agregar un script que añada de nuevo el mismo item al sessionStorage:

```
let previousItem = sessionStorage.getItem("carrito")
sessionStorage.setItem("carrito", previousItem)
```

**Mas info:**

sessionStorage es un almacenamiento que perdura durante toda la sesión (navegación) del usuario en tu sitio web. Podes aprender más en la [documentación oficial.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Vale pa gracias